# Maven, run a java method or script before war is about to be built

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin

I am thinking of using a template engine to generate the web.xml and other things.

Is there as way to to run a java file or a script before the **maven install command**? Or before the war is generated.

I am not sure what the phase should be, but basically **before anyone else** looks at the web.xml so I can touch it to **make a new valid one**.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) to run either a program/script (using the [exec goal](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html)) or a Java program (using the [java goal](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html)).

The phase immediately before `package` is `prepare-package` (see the Default lifecycle in the [Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)), so you could use that. But you might prefer to generate the web.xml earlier in the lifecycle (even as early as `generate-resources`).

Putting these together, you might try something like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>your_packaging_script</executable>
      <!-- optional -->
      <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
      <arguments>
        <argument>--some-option</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Alternatively, you might consider [writing your own plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html), especially if you think the idea would be useful for more than one project.

Comment: Is there a way to run the plugin at profile activation without mentioning it in project pom.xml?
There seems to be no <plugins> section in <profile>.